# How do I convert this one element of the array to utf-8?

Tags: php, zend-framework, utf-8, zend-gdata

Using Zend _gdata.  For some reason, recently the $when string is no longer utf-8.  I need to convert it to utf-8.  All the other fields are working fine.

```
   foreach ($feed as $event) { //iterating through all events

      $contentText = stripslashes($event->content->text); //striping any escape character
      $contentText = preg_replace('/\<br \/\>[\n\t\s]{1,}\<br \/\>/','<br />',stripslashes($event->content->text)); //replacing multiple breaks with a single break
      $contentText = explode('<br />',$contentText); //splitting data by break tag

      $eventData = filterEventDetails($contentText);
      $when = $eventData['when'];
      $where = $eventData['where'];
      $duration = $eventData['duration'];
      $title = stripslashes($event->title);
      echo '<li class="pastShows">' . $when . " - " . $title . ", " . $where . '</li>';
   }
```

How do I make `$when` utf-8?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on what encoding that string is using, you should be able to encode it to UTF-8 using one of the following functions :

- [**`utf8_encode()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php)
- [**`iconv()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php)

For example :

```
$when = utf8_encode($eventData['when']);
```

Or :

```
$when = iconv('ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8', $eventData['when']);
```

Comment: Well this issue is really weird.  I'm seing I guess it's not a unicode issue.  If you look here http://rattletree.com/upcomingshows2.php  You can see in the first column the Month name is getting all screwed up.  But using mb_detect_encoding, it is telling me its utf-8.

Comment: This is a bummer.  It was working a week ago and now this.  I have no idea how to even address this problem :(

Comment: Well I did find this thread-looks like it's a google issue http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Calendar/thread?tid=25ac3d762b235a51&hl=en

Comment: Oh, nice :-) maybe the `hl=en` solution will work for you too ?

Comment: I hope so. I need to figure out how to append that since I am retrieving the feed as an object. I'll post a new question. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If the string is in Latin1 you can just do what Pascal suggests.

Otherwise you need to find out which encoding it is.
Therefor check your php.ini settings or you can try to detect it by mb_detect_encoding (be aware it's not fail prove)